# Firefox: request using firefox console to see the messages

Tags: authentication, firefox, telegram, messenger

I want to see the messengers'(such as telegram) messages using sending requests in firefox console. Is it possible? And if it is, how can I do it?

If it is impossible to see the messages this way, how can I do it? Mention that I don't want to using API. I tried to write my own crawler using scrapy, but I had problems for authentication. :(

Thank you